# My character got whipped and I want to know whether the extent of her injuries is possibe

Tags: warfare, weapons, humans

My original character got whipped and I don't want any scarring to happen. What I imagine is a that is bruised skin with black lines criss-crossing all over the back. The skin is not broken.
Is it possible for her to just come out with bruises that fade with time? Or if not then what will result in the marks as I mentioned above?

Comment: Bruises which don't break the skin (or the bones, or any internal organs) heal without any trace. Have you never been a child?

Comment: What is an Oc?.

Comment: @rek
I suspect it's Original Character.  (Fanfic term.)

Comment: I found this: https://springhole.net/writing/oc-protagonist-fanfiction.htm and it still doesn't friggin' tell you what OC stands for.

Comment: @rek -- A non-rhotic British Orc.

Comment: VTC:Needs Details. I haven't the foggiest idea what "whipped" means here. If possible I'd also VTC:Needs Focus. You're asking multiple questions (you get one). "Is it possible for her to come out with bruises?" presupposes you're asking about the result of a (not defined) beating. "What will result in..." is asking us to define the beating. From our [help/on-topic], "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, **not to tell your story**." Asking us to describe the beating is asking us to tell your story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No Worries!**

Scars happen when the skin is torn, cut or otherwise broken.

Your character's skin hasn't been torn, cut or otherwise broken, so no scars will form.